# How to transform HTML table into CSS positioning?

Tags: html, css

Assume I have the following HTML code:

```
<form name="marketplace" method="post" action="marketplace">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="input"><label>Key: <input type="checkbox" name="searchkeys" value="on" id="marketplace_key_checkbox" data-showerrors="false"></label></td>
            <td class="input"><select name="key" id="marketplace_key_select"></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="input"><label>Mod: <input type="checkbox" name="searchmods" value="on" id="marketplace_mod_checkbox" data-showerrors="false"></label></td>
            <td class="input"><select name="mod" id="marketplace_mod_select"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

How would I get the same visual representation (seen on http://jsfiddle.net/8H59u/) by using CSS3 **without** `table`s? I'm a bit lost on where to start, any tips would be appreciated. (No, you do not need to make my code)

Also as an extra: Am I correct that we should not be using `table` for layout positioning?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you shouldn't use tables for this. But I do, all the time. Ask me if I give a damn.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in that you should not use tables for positioning as it's usually seen as bad practice. You should use divs and position them in css using display, float, etc. (but nobody can stop you from using tables.)

Comment: for tight positioning you can use `position:relative` on the divs and adjust the left and right positioning as needed.

Comment: I'm also planning to do some more tricky stuff, so I do like to get rid of the tables if possible...

Comment: For layout not -- but for tabular data yes. http://jsfiddle.net/8H59u/4/ . Also this isn't CSS3

Comment: What do you think *tabular data* is (go ahead, think about it for a bit)?  There's no reason why a collection of key/value pairs *can't* be tabular data.  There's a clear relationship between the contents of the cells, which is more than can be said about the good old days of using tables to lay out your entire site.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/8H59u/2/

Basically, apply `display:inline-block` then set a fixed width on them.

Comment: This however uses a fixed with (100px in the example), whereas to really mimic the tables behaviour I'd want the width to be as minimal as possible. Would that also be possible?

Comment: Nope. Well, *maybe*, but you'd have to put the two "label" elements in one container, the two "select"s in another... basically, rearranging the HTML into something mangled.

Comment: I think i'll go with the `table`s still then... Seems like my quest for perfectness ends here, if CSS even cannot mimick what tables can do, then it simply ends.

Comment: @skiwi what about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a6YX6/1/)? It should take up a minimal amount of space, and you don't set any fixed values.

Comment: @skiwi Heh, I don't blame you. Like I said above, tables *work*. The main problem people have is when you hack around with empty table cells to simulate padding and stuff. But many people have just blown the "anti-table" thing way out of proportion.

Comment: Would it be okay though to give those "empty-hack" cells a `class` and then use that in CSS? I think for my system, a small system, tables still seem to be the way to go.

Comment: Honestly, if it works, it's okay by me. If you want to go an extra length, try copy-pasting the rendered page into Notepad, and if it looks reasonable there then you're doing pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

You could even use `display: table-cell` and `display: table`, if you only need to support IE8+.  I think the general idea behind not using tables for layout is to keep your styles separate from your markup, so that you can easily change the appearance in the future without having to change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

> Also as an extra: Am I correct that we should not be using table for
>   layout positioning?

**Yes**. Table is for tabular data:
From W3 [table section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html):

> Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media.

Avoid table in layout is what we call [Tableless](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto).

---

Three options to solve problem:

**option 1:** using divs with display table/table-cell:

```
display: table;
display: table-cell;
```

- not accepted in all browsers.

**option 2:**

```
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
min-width: 120px;
max-width: 200px;
```

**option 3:**

```
float: left;
width: 20%;
min-width: 120px;
max-width: 200px;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also as an extra: Am I correct that we should not be using table for
>   layout positioning?

**Yes..!!** You **shouldn't** use **TABLE** for **Layout**

**HTML**

```
 <form name="marketplace" method="post" action="marketplace">
   <div id="wrapper"> <div class="leftkey"><label>Key: <input type="checkbox" name="searchkeys" value="on" id="marketplace_key_checkbox" data-showerrors="false"/></label></div>
    <div class="rightkey"><select name="key" id="marketplace_key_select"><option>Test</option></select></div>
    <div class="leftkey"><label>Mod: <input type="checkbox" name="searchmods" value="on" id="marketplace_mod_checkbox" data-showerrors="false"/></label></div>
    <div class="rightkey"><select name="mod" id="marketplace_mod_select"><option>Test</option></select></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    width:200px;
}
.leftkey
{ width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.rightkey
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    width:100px;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8H59u/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  Just use div / span tags instead of tables.  This renders identically to your original code, and doesn't even use any CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/8H59u/13/

```
<form name="marketplace" method="post" action="marketplace">
    <div class="inputParent">
        <label>Key:
            <input type="checkbox" name="searchkeys" value="on" id="marketplace_key_checkbox" data-showerrors="false">
        </label> <span class="inputChild"><select name="key" id="marketplace_key_select"><option>Test</option></select></span>
    </div>
    <div class="inputParent">
        <label>Mod:
            <input type="checkbox" name="searchmods" value="on" id="marketplace_mod_checkbox" data-showerrors="false">
        </label> <span class="inputChild"><select name="mod" id="marketplace_mod_select"><option>Test</option></select></span>
    </div>
```